# Follow-on to tabulary + longtable + captioning

Tags: captions, longtable, itemize, tabulary, varwidth

I was able to use the coding provided by Justibus: [Several caption problems in longtable and tabulary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197687/several-caption-problems-in-longtable-and-tabulary).

What my question is - now that i've been able to make my table wrap columns and break over multiple pages whilst maintaining tabulary. I now find that the first column (in my case of three colunns) is being compressed to far in it's appearance.

How can i set a minimum limit of compression to the columns?

My understanding of coding is beginning and so have been unable to find a clear explanation on in other posts of how to put a minimum column width limit with tabulary.

Any help with this would be appreciated and if the list in the final cell could be itemized it would be excellent.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false, format=plain}

\usepackage{tabulary, booktabs, longtable, ltcaption}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

%% define a new envrionment which marries longtable with tabulary
\makeatletter
\def\ltabulary{%
\def\endfirsthead{\\}%
\def\endhead{\\}%
\def\endfoot{\\}%
\def\endlastfoot{\\}%
\def\tabulary{%
  \def\TY@final{%
\def\endfirsthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}%
\def\endhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@head}%
\def\endfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@foot}%
\def\endlastfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}%
\longtable}%
  \let\endTY@final\endlongtable
  \TY@tabular}%
\dimen@\columnwidth
\advance\dimen@-\LTleft
\advance\dimen@-\LTright
\tabulary\dimen@}
\def\endltabulary{\endtabulary}
\makeatother
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary (see there for usage)

\begin{document}
%   \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
%   \setlength\LTright{0pt}
%   \captionof{table}{Example of long table over multiple pages}
    \begin{ltabulary}{LLL}
        \caption{Common Medications}\\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Drug Name}                  &\textbf{Dosing Schedule}        & \textbf{Indications/Comments}  \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{(continued)}\\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Drug Name}                  &\textbf{Dosing Schedule}        & \textbf{Indications/Comments}  \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes

        \begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{TableNotes}

        \endlastfoot
       % \textbf{Drug Name}                  &\textbf{Dosing Schedule}        & \textbf{Indications/Comments}  \\
        %\hline
        Betamethasone Valerate (Celestone) & 12 mg IM q24h x 2 doses & Enhancement of Foetal Pulmonary maturity for PTL\\
        \\
        Methylergonavine maleate (Ergotamine)   &0.25 mg IM q5min up to 1.25 mg or IV bolus 0.125 mg    &Treatment of uterine atony\\
        \\
        Rh IgG (Rhogam)     &300$\mu$g IM x 1 dose  &Given to Rh negative women \newline Routinely at 28 wks GA \newline Within 72 h of birth of Rh +ve foetus positive \newline Positive Kleihauer-Betke test \newline With any invasive procedure in pregnancy \newline Ectopic pregnancy \newline Antepartum haemorrhage \newline Miscarriage or TA (dose: 50 $\mu$g IM only) \\



    \end{ltabulary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use `\setlength\tymin{...}` to set a minimum compression, or simply use a fixed with `p` column for the first column.

Comment: your example code produces `! Package caption Error: \caption outside float.`

Answer (score 3):

If you add some hyphenation points and restrict each column to `.2\textwidth` you get

[image]

If you use `.25\textwidth` it doesn't need to hyphenate in this case, so you can choose:-)

(The `\caption` usage still needs fixing)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false, format=plain}

\usepackage{tabulary, booktabs, longtable, ltcaption}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

%% define a new envrionment which marries longtable with tabulary
\makeatletter
\def\ltabulary{%
\def\endfirsthead{\\}%
\def\endhead{\\}%
\def\endfoot{\\}%
\def\endlastfoot{\\}%
\def\tabulary{%
  \def\TY@final{%
\def\endfirsthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}%
\def\endhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@head}%
\def\endfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@foot}%
\def\endlastfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}%
\longtable}%
  \let\endTY@final\endlongtable
  \TY@tabular}%
\dimen@\columnwidth
\advance\dimen@-\LTleft
\advance\dimen@-\LTright
\tabulary\dimen@}
\def\endltabulary{\endtabulary}
\makeatother
% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary (see there for usage)

\begin{document}
\setlength\tymin{.2\textwidth}
%   \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
%   \setlength\LTright{0pt}
%   \captionof{table}{Example of long table over multiple pages
\makeatletter
    \begin{ltabulary}{LLL}
        \caption{Common Medications}\\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Drug Name}                  &\textbf{Dosing Schedule}        & \textbf{Indications/Comments}  \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{(continued)}\\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Drug Name}                  &\textbf{Dosing Schedule}        & \textbf{Indications/Comments}  \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes

        \begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{TableNotes}

        \endlastfoot
       % \textbf{Drug Name}                  &\textbf{Dosing Schedule}        & \textbf{Indications/Comments}  \\
        %\hline
        Beta\-metha\-sone Valerate (Celestone) & 12 mg IM q24h x 2 doses & Enhancement of Foetal Pulmonary maturity for PTL\\
        \\
        Methyl\-ergon\-avine maleate (Ergotamine)   &0.25 mg IM q5min up to 1.25 mg or IV bolus 0.125 mg    &Treatment of uterine atony\\
        \\
        Rh IgG (Rhogam)     &300$\mu$g IM x 1 dose  &Given to Rh negative women \newline Routinely at 28 wks GA \newline Within 72 h of birth of Rh +ve foetus positive \newline Positive Kleihauer-Betke test \newline With any invasive procedure in pregnancy \newline Ectopic pregnancy \newline Antepartum haemorrhage \newline Miscarriage or TA (dose: 50 $\mu$g IM only) \\



    \end{ltabulary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this format what would be the easiest way to include the bulleting/numbering of items in the list?

Comment: @Mitchell which list? you mean you want a bullet in each row of the table? you could have a new first `c` column with `\textbullet` in each cell?

Comment: Just in the cell: R3,C3; where it has a bunch of new lines.

Comment: @Mitchell lists don't work in tabulary (sorry) there is a fix here then you will be able to use `\begin{itemize}` for a bullet list as normal.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204881/error-missing-endgroup-for-table-tabulary-with-bullet-list/204926#204926