# tabulary and itemize with strange error

Tags: itemize, tabulary

I tried to set up itemize within a tabulary, but get a "Missing \endcsname".

My MWE:

```
   \documentclass{scrbook} 
   \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
   \usepackage{multirow} 
   \usepackage{tabulary}
   
   \begin{document}
   \chapter{Theoretical Background}
   \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
         \begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{|L|L|}
           \hline
            Decision level & Type  \\
            \hline 
            \multirow{12}{*}
               \begin{itemize}
                   \item strategic
                   \item tactical
               \end{itemize} &
               \begin{itemize}
                   \item stochastic
                   \item deterministic
               \end{itemize}   \\
           \hline  
       \end{tabulary}
   \end{table} \\
   \end{document}
```

Output is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./00_main_document english.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ragged2e/ragged2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabulary/tabulary.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./00_main_document english.aux) ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
chapter 1.
./00_main_document english.tex:26: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.26    \end{tabulary}
                    
? 
Process aborted
```

Any hints?

Comment: also don't put `\\ ` after `\end{table}`  it generates an error and can not do anything useful.

Comment: What's the purpose of `\multirow{12}{*}`?

Comment: @Mico I thought something like this was necessary to have the itemize block fit in the cell of the table. Saw it in a lot of examples, but didn't really understand it.

Comment: I have no idea if multirow works in tabulary (certainly it was never tested) a 12 row span in a 1 row table seems brave. For lists you can make them work with some effort see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204926/1090  but really it would be simpler to use a normal tabular here and two  columns

Comment: @Ariser you are saying that the first cell should span over 12 rows of the table, but there are not 12 rows in this table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, removed the \\. When I omit the multirow statement I get a different error. And the linked examples look tedious. Perhaps I should resort to tabular. My actual table in fact has 7 columns, but I reduced it to 2 for the MWE. Some of the items in the other rows will have longer text which has to be wrapped within the column. That's why I thought that tabulary might be a good idea.

Comment: I wrote tabulary and its main use is for automated workflows where the table columns need to be allocated automatically., if you are hand writing a document you can use a normal table and p columns and chose the widths by hand which gives more control and a better result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems easier to use a standard `tabular` here

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
   \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
 
   
   \begin{document}
   \chapter{Theoretical Background}
   \begin{table}[htbp] % not just h
        % \centering % doesn't really do anything as the table is full width
         % \begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{|L|L|}
   \begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{0.5\dimexpr\textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep}|}}
         % simpler to use tabular
           \hline
            Decision level & Type  \\
            \hline 
           %%% \multirow{12}{*} there are not 12 rows to spane
               \begin{itemize}
                   \item strategic
                   \item tactical
               \end{itemize} &
               \begin{itemize}
                   \item stochastic
                   \item deterministic
               \end{itemize} \\
           \hline  
       \end{tabular}
   \end{table} % \\ % never use \\ here 
   \end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good. I'm going to test it on my real table.

Comment: This solution works, however, I guess I have to do a lot to make it look nice.

Comment: @Ariser tabulary produces exactly the same layout as the tabular solution shown here except that it chooses the width of each `p{..}` column via a rough heuristic that tries to give columns with more text a wider space. But if you set the p{..} widths by hand then you get more control.

Comment: @Ariser, you still can stick with `tabulary` is you encapsulate `itemize` in a `minipage`: `\begin{minipage}{\hsize}\smallskip
        \begin{itemize}
           \item strategic
           \item tactical
       \end{itemize}`. However, you will get nicer result with use of the `enumitem` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right. I wil delete y comments soon.